# Creating Data Source for Oracle in WSO2 Data Services Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I have a Oracle Database 12c and I want to create a Data source for that in WSO2 Data Services Server.

I have downloaded ojdbc7.jar and copied into repository/components/lib folder of WSO2 Data Services Server

While Creating Data source from DSS UI, it is asking for jdbc:oracle:[drivertype]:[username/password]@[host]:[port]/[database]

I am confused with "drivertype" what should be the value of drivertype?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be one of one of `oci, thin, or kprb (server-side internal)`.

Read this for more information: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#05_04

Comment: "jdbc:oracle:thin:xx/xxx@xx.xx.xx.x:1521/xx"; Got Error: "Error loading Driver class:oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver cannot be found by org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.rdbms_4.4.9"

Comment: try `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver`

Comment: where i have to try this?

Comment: in datasource configuration. instead of `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`

Comment: got error: Error loading Driver class:oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver cannot be found by org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.rdbms_4.4.9

Comment: Are you sure you have the jar in `repository/components/lib`? Remove if you have any oracle JDBC drivers in `repository/components/dropins`.

Answer (score 1):

Driver type should be 'thin'[[1]](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DSS311/Setting+up+with+Oracle). ojdbc7 comes under JDBC thin [[2]](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/jdbc-drivers-12c-download-1958347.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is my config for an Oracle DB:

```
<config id="etecsa2Oracle">
    <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.user">schemaName</property>
    <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.password">userPassword</property>
    <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.protocol">jdbc:oracle:thin:schemaName/userPassword@localhost:1521/ORCL</property>
    <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.driver">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
    <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.minpoolsize"/>
    <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.maxpoolsize"/>
    <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.validation_query"/>
</config>
```

Inside component/lib I put this jar: ojdbc6.jar